# Aruba with Thor, the feature fails with weird issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, thor, aruba

Building a CLI app using Thor and Aruba as testing framework.

Posted this issue at the Aruba's issues at github https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/issues/76 but still no comments at all.

So I'm posting it here so that I can get some feedback.

### Issue

There are 2 scenarios in the `features/login.feature` file
The difference between the scenarios is that one uses `Then I debug` step, other doesn't.

When I run `bundle exec cucumber features/`, the one without debugger step fails. Aruba cannot catch the output.

But the one with debugger step, halts and when I press `c` to continue, Aruba can catch the output and it passes.

Banging my head since past 2 days, googled the whole earth, but couldn't find whats the issue is.

I've uploaded the repo at https://github.com/millisami/aruba_thor so that someone can see the issue.

To run the feature, just run `bundle exec cucumber features`.

Answer (score -2):

I found the workaround myself.
Thanks to those who read this issue.

Comment: @NeilMiddleton https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/issues/76#issuecomment-1464732 this might help you out